# Meteor.user custom field displaying a single list of items in one html tag instead of each item in its own tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

I have a custom user field that get populated by the user on click of a button with  an id of an item from another collection, however when i return it, i get a single list of the items in one html tag, instead of returning each saved item in its own tag with the result looking like this

[image]

i.e its like this

```
<p>CategoryPublication-98,CategoryPublication-2,CategoryPublication-57<p>
```

when it should be like this

```
    <p>CategoryPublication-98</p>
    <p>CategoryPublication-2</p>
    <p>CategoryPublication-57</p>
```

this is my publish

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id:{$in:fields.name}}).fetch();
});
```

my html

```
<template name="userTimeline">

  {{#if currentUser}}
  <div class="timeline-user">
{{#each name}}
 <p>{{name}}</p>

  {{/each}}
  </div>

{{/if}}
</template>
```

my helper

```
Template.userTimeline.helpers({

  name: function() {
    return Meteor.user().name;
  }
});
```

my insert

```
Template.CategoriesMain.events({
  'click .toggle-category': function(e){
          var ob = this._id;
          var id = $.makeArray( ob );

          console.log(id);

          e.preventDefault();
          Meteor.call('addingCategory', id, function(error, user){ console.log(id)});
      },
});
```

My methods

```
Meteor.methods({
    addingCategory: function(name) {
        console.log(Meteor.userId());
        Meteor.users.update({
      _id: Meteor.userId()
    },
    {
      $addToSet: {

        name: name
      }
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have:

```
{{#each name}}
  <p>{{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

There's ambiguity about the value of `name` in the inner `<p></p>`. Since you're just returning an array of strings instead of objects there is no `name` key in the array.

Instead do:

```
{{#each name}}
  <p>{{this}}</p>
{{/each}}
```